# Is there anyway to make SQL Server send a string to a C# application?

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2, and I would like to send a string from the server to my c# application. Not vice-versa. I don't want my C# application to go and ask if there is new data in my database, I want that the SQL Server to send the data (string) to my C# application.

Is it possible to make SQL Server as a sender and the C# application as a receiver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC the SqlDependency actually works by polling the database, so you are actually just offloading the work of "going and asking" to another layer. If you really just want to send a message to the app from the db server, you could open a port (or expose a web service) in your app, then xp_cmdshell from SQL Server to call a command line app that uses that port/service to send a message. There may be other ways, too, and this would have to be done either behind a firewall or with proper security measure in place.

Comment: do you hae anykind of examples about this so I could read more about it, even some keywords to use might be quite useful. and thanx for telling me that SqlDependency works by polling, coz i've spent 45 minutes trying to find out where is the sending part on the databse..

Comment: I don't have docs on this, but I think we discovered it by using the activity monitor feature in SSMS...I think it requires the use of the Service Broker, which does the actually polling of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Yous hould have a look at [`SqlDependancy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx). Here is a description of how to use it in a windows app: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a52dhwx7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx